# Spring-boot: caching Dao Objects

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching, redis

I am searching for a good solution/practice to cache Dao objects into redis. Details below:

Lets say I have a table 'Users' and a DAO named 'UserDao' which has functions like:

```
User findByUserId(Long userId);
List<User> findAllWithUserIds(List<Long> userIdList);
```

Now I want to store 'User' objects into redis, so that I don't have to query them from database everytime.

Are there any existing implementations?

I thought of using @Cacheable, implemention would be something like:

```
@Cacheable
public User findByUserIdCached(Long userId) {
       <<query-dao>>
}

@Cacheable
public User findAllByUserIdListCached(List<Long> userIdList) {
       <<query-dao>>
}
```

Problem with this approach is that findAllByUserIds() cache will increase drastically with arguments of permutations of userIdList.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: You can write your DAO as a write-through cache backed by Redis. So: you perform a query and first check if users with given IDs are already stored in cache and query only for those absent. Once absent ones are returned from the DB you merge new entries and cached entries into 1 collection and return it to the calling method.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of your application? Also, if your Redis cache is on a different machine, you seem to assume that caching an object in Redis will be faster than caching it in the database, which is most likely true, but typically caches are in local memory and not remote, since it is the round-trip latency that kills performance.

Comment: I was planning to deploy redis-cache in the same subnet, do you think latency is still a problem? And what do you mean by caching in the database? Caching in database (e.g. mysql) is generally limited, in case of big tables (in my case around 2-3 million rows) db caching will not be effective.. Am I wrong?